# Does a swing-slide frameless glass door mechanism exist?

Tags: bathroom, doors, shower, glass

I would like to have glass around my square-ish shower (90cm × 100cm) in bathroom corner. It should only consist of two pieces:

1. the fixed wall (100cm wide)
2. door (90cm)

But instead of swinging doors opening inwards/outwards I'd like doors to swing-slide open inwards.

Looking from top down doors would open this way:

[image: Sketch of slide-swing doors]

Benefits of such door mechanism:

1. easy shower access - door never in the way
2. water dripping off the doors goes inside shower
3. full width door without any wall side fixed glass

I would like to know if anyone has seen this kind of mechanism. I know how such mechanism should work but I don't know whether it's possible to buy it anywhere. I expect doors to be top hung (6mm toughened glass would weight somewhere around 30kg) with a slide running at the top side on the wall for the doors to open correctly. The main problem there may be is the weight of glass but I suppose it could be done without additional bottom support.

Would I have to contract someone to create such mech for me or is it possible to buy it anywhere? Or maybe somebody has already seen such product somewhere?

Comment: I doubt you could accomplish a smooth sliding action with a slide only on the top. However, a bottom slide will interfere with the usage of the shower and will be a nightmare to keep clean.

Comment: @EliIser: I suppose door weight will be helpful in this regard. And if all turning parts (three) had quality bearings I suppose it could work ok, don't you think? And if I'd use bottom slide as well it could be upside down so no water would be able to get in and would stabilize doors vertically.

Comment: it's not the sliding itself that I see as problematic - it's hanging a tall sheet of glass off of one edge. I think that the glass on the bottom side will move in a direction perpendicular to the slide. I have a regular sliding glass shower door with a slide on top and a tiny (~2 CM) U channel on the bottom to keep the door from swinging as I've described.

Comment: @EliIser: Can you take a picture and post it so I can see what your doors and mech look like?

Comment: I'l try to snap some photos at the evening.

Comment: -1 "Does X exist" is typically considered a shopping question. http://meta.diy.stackexchange.com/questions/607/can-we-discourage-shop-for-me-type-questions

Comment: A 90 degree TV bracket comes into mind. It will most likely require extreme DIY skills and I did start to write an answer- but it just seems preposterous proposition that might not fit as an answer on this site. I was thinking of removing the VESA plate (that hold the TV) and construct a DIY "something" to hold the glass from the TOP. That way you can move the wall of glass "extended" or fold it back to the wall "retracted/folded" - I have not seen such doors any where, neither fitted or fittings. Possibly there are some mega expensive solutions somewhere for this.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on my comment: I think that the main problem with the proposed setup is lacking a slide or rail on the bottom. Without a slide on the bottom the glass door can swing perpendicular to the sliding direction. See the below explanation for what I mean.

I have a sliding shower door with a sliding mechanism on the top (a stainless steel rail with 2 wheels per door on top of the rail) and a tiny U channel on the bottom to keep the door from swinging. I know, I need to clean the shower a little...

[image: Top sliding rail]

The door is sliding in the direction of the blue arrows. The U channel on the bottom is keeping the door from swinging in the direction of the red arrows. This U channel is about 2 CM long and seems to be made from aluminium.

[image: Bottom channel]